# ORA-12560 occurs after creating a pyinstaller .exe file using python cx_Oracle code

Tags: python, database, oracle, pyinstaller, cx-oracle

When I run it as a python code before making it into an .exe file, the db connection works fine..

After creating an .exe file with the pyinstaller command, it ends with the error below.

---

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "main.py",line 20, in <module>
```

cx_Oracle.DatabaseError : ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error

[30880] Failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception!

---

LOCATION = r"D:\instantclient_19_14"

os.environ["PATH"] = LOCATION + ";" + os.environ["PATH"]

conn = o.connect('{}/{}@{}:{}/{}'.format( USERNAME, PASSWORD, IP, PORT, SID ) )

- OS : Windows10
- Python : 3.8
- remote OS : Windows server 2016
- remote Oracle DB Ver : 12.1

What could be the cause?

thanks in advance..

Comment: Are you running pyinstaller from a virutalenv that contains all of the necessary dependencies and is pyinstaller able to locate them? i.e. is cx-oracle getting bundled into the exe?

Comment: If pyinstaller puts the resulting file in a different folder from the original script then relative paths won't work properly.

Comment: Start by reading the cx_Oracle doc https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/initialization.html and use `init_oracle_client()` instead of hacking with PATH. Make sure there is no other Oracle software in PATH that could be clashing.  Make sure you are using the DB servce name, not the SID, since the latter won't work with the Easy Connect Syntax.  If you only have a SID, use makedsn() - see the doc.

Comment: I found the cause.
My workspace is a network drive.
When executing pyinstaller .exe from a network drive, the above-mentioned error occurs.
When I use the local C drive as the work space, it works normally.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution.